# How do I find ID of an element by it's classname?

Tags: jquery

How can I find the ID of the element that has the class `active`?

```
<a id='1' >A</a>
<a id='2' >B</a>
<a id='3' class='active'>C</a>
<a id='4' >D</a>
<a id='5' >E</a>
<a id='6' >F</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attr()`

```
$('a.active').attr('id');
```